# Handling matrices using Brobdingnag package

Tags: r, matrix, bignum

I need to build a matrix with extremely small entries.
So far I realized that the fastest way to define the kind of matrix that I need is:

1. Define a vectorized function of coordinates:

   ```
   func = function(m,n){...}
   ```
2. Combine every possible coordinate using outer:

   ```
   matrix = outer(1:100,1:100,FUN=func)
   ```

Having to deal with extremely small numbers I work in `func`'s environment using brob numbers, its output will therefore be of the same type of a brob:

```
typeof(func(0:100,0:100) )
[1] "S4"
```

If I directly plug two vectors 0:100 in my function `func` it returns a vector of brobs but if I try to use it with outer I get the error:

```
Error in outer(1:100, 1:100, FUN = func) : invalid first argument
```

I suppose this is because package Brobdingnag can somehow deal with vectors but not with matrices. Is it right? Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Why don't you work with the logs of your numbers? That is the typical solution if numbers are so small that floating point precision becomes a problem.

Comment: I need to use this matrix as a set of ordinary differential equations to solve eventually with "expoRkit" or "ode". With logs there's no way to do that and even if I make all calculations with logs and I exponentiate right before producing the output accuracy will be lost either way.

Comment: And these functions support arbitrary precision arithmetics?

Comment: All that I do is performing sums, multiplications and exponentiation. All of those operations are handled by Brobdingnag package.
The only problem is when I try to build a matrix with them using outer.